# Micronaut Testing with JWT Authentication multiple Service

Tags: micronaut

I have multiples Services: `ServiceA`, `ServiceB`, `ServiceC` with JWT Authentication and Propagation enabled. The service responsible to authenticate the users is `ServiceA`.

So how can I testing (JUnit5) my services `B` and `C` if authentication is enabled and this services don't know how to authenticate?

```
[main] INFO  i.m.context.env.DefaultEnvironment - Established active environments: [test]
[nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] DEBUG i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Sending HTTP Request: POST /serviceB/order/item
[nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] DEBUG i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Chosen Server: localhost(33006)
[nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzaGVybG9jayIsIm5iZiI6MTU4MTI3NjA2NSwicm9sZXMiOltdLCJpc3MiOiJ1c2VyIiwiZXhwIjoxNTgxMjc5NjY1LCJpYXQiOjE1ODEyNzYwNjV9.yrVqAluyZvKIGjtu4tDVSnZZiZ8kdhduN20n1xd1z6U
[nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - host: localhost:33006
[nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - connection: close
[nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - content-type: application/json
[nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - content-length: 2
[nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Request Body
[nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - HTTP Client Response Received for Request: POST http://localhost:33006/serviceB/order/item
[nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Status Code: 403 Forbidden
[nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - Date: Sun, 9 Feb 2020 19:23:08 GMT
[nioEventLoopGroup-1-3] TRACE i.m.http.client.DefaultHttpClient - connection: close
```

Using: `Micronaut 1.3.0`, `JDK 1.8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [gitter.im/micronautfw](https://gitter.im/micronautfw/questions?at=5c3e05b60721b912a584999e) there is an answer using `MockAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider` and `SecurityBypassFilter implements HttpClientFilter` to Mock the authentication logic.

```java
    package demo

    import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Requires
    import io.micronaut.context.env.Environment
    import io.micronaut.security.authentication.AuthenticationFailed
    import io.micronaut.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider
    import io.micronaut.security.authentication.AuthenticationRequest
    import io.micronaut.security.authentication.AuthenticationResponse
    import io.micronaut.security.authentication.UserDetails
    import io.reactivex.Flowable
    import org.reactivestreams.Publisher

    import javax.inject.Singleton

    @Requires(env = Environment.TEST)
    @Requires(property = 'spec.name', notEquals = 'SecuritySpec')
    @Singleton
    class MockAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

        @Override
        Publisher<AuthenticationResponse> authenticate(AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest) {
            if ( authenticationRequest.identity == 'user' && authenticationRequest.secret == 'password' ) {
                return Flowable.just(new UserDetails('user', []))
            }
            return Flowable.just(new AuthenticationFailed())
        }
    }
```

and

```java
    package groovycalamari.bookmark

    import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Requires
    import io.micronaut.context.env.Environment
    import io.micronaut.http.HttpResponse
    import io.micronaut.http.MutableHttpRequest
    import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Filter
    import io.micronaut.http.filter.ClientFilterChain
    import io.micronaut.http.filter.HttpClientFilter
    import org.reactivestreams.Publisher

    @Filter('/**')
    @Requires(env = Environment.TEST)
    @Requires(property = 'spec.name', notEquals = 'SecuritySpec')
    class SecurityBypassFilter implements HttpClientFilter {

        @Override
        Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> doFilter(MutableHttpRequest<?> request, ClientFilterChain chain) {
            request.basicAuth('user', 'password')
            return chain.proceed(request)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to use JWT token:

```java
@Filter("/**")
@Requires(env = Environment.TEST)
@Requires(property = "spec.name", notEquals = "SecuritySpec")
public class MockSecurityBypassFilter implements HttpClientFilter
{
    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MockSecurityBypassFilter.class);
    
    @Override
    public Publisher<? extends HttpResponse<?>> doFilter(MutableHttpRequest<?> request, ClientFilterChain chain)
    {
        LOG.info(">>> Mock Security Filter automatic sign in");
        // token expire at -> Saturday, April 20, 2030 9:39:44 PM GMT-03:00
        final String JWT_TOKEN = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.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.-MXKLJe7iqpAcdViFtcHFg2Yvcypf9E3KVLyxc";
        request.bearerAuth(JWT_TOKEN);
        return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
```